# RegEx to remove every instance of two characters?

Tags: regex

I have a question I've been wresteling with for most of the weekend. I have a database that outputs results to me in the following format:

```
0x50006100720074006900740069006F006E005400650073007400
```

I'm looking for a regex to remove all of the 00s from the result and return just the other hex. For example, I'd like to remove the following from the above (without the spaces, sorry, but the bold is a bit finnicky)

0x50 **00** 61 **00** 72 **00** 74 **00** 69 **00** 74 **00** 69 **00** 6F **00** 6E **00** 54 **00** 65 **00** 73 **00** 74 **00**

And just return

```
506172746974696F6E54657374
```

Any ideas? Thank you very much!

Comment: Why not just use an edit-replace, i.e. replace "00" with ""?

Comment: I'm afraid the edit-replace will match the first instance of two 0's it finds. For example, 5000 it would match 5*00*0. In addition, I need to decode the rsult programaticcaly as I will be working with a large result set.

Comment: Do all zeroes need to be on even positions? I.e., should it not match the sequence `50 0A`, for example?

Comment: Why is removing the middle in `5<b>00</b>0` a problem -- it gives the same result, doesn't it?

Comment: The result will always be in the format of 0xYY00ZZ00 etc. So yes, all the 00s will be in the same posiiton - I will have 2 bytes that are relevant and two bytes that I need to discard.

Comment: Just tell me you're not trying to convert UTF-16 to ASCII this way, do you?

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski This is in the database of a piece of enterprise software... I was pretty dumbfounded when I saw it as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a lookahead that forces the number of hex digits to the right to always be even.

This works in TextWrangler:

```
00(?=([0-9A-F]{2})*$)
```